# I am trying to calculate the cheapest price for a good in R based on availability

Tags: r

I have a dataframe based on the below:

```
vendor <- c("John", "Matt", "Julie", "Ryan","John", "Matt", "Julie", "Ryan")

fruit <- c("apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange")

Total_Order <- c(1000,1000,1000,1000,500,500,500,500)

vendor_availability <- c(500,200,300,400, 100,300,400,50)

price_per_unit <- c(.1,.05,.07,.2, .2,.25,.3,.5)

fruit_orders <- data.frame(vendor, fruit, Total_Order, vendor_availability, price_per_unit)
```

And I am trying to fill my total order with the cheapest combination of vendors for each type of fruit and calculate what that cost would be per fruit.

I proxied a solution by using data.table:

```
fruit$50cover <- fruit$vendor_availability > fruit$Total_Order

df <- subset(fruit, 50cover = TRUE)

    library(data.table)
df1 < setDT(fruit_orders)[,list(price_per_unit = min(price_per_unit)),
   by=fruit]
```

But that is a bad estimate of what it should be.

The answer clearly should be:

apple .081

orange .25

thank you in advanced for any thoughts or direction!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Sounds like a genetic algorithm optimisation question. See example on how GA is used to solve the knapsack problem -  http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution I have come up with using library `dplyr`. The logic is as follows. First, arrange the data by fruit, price per unit and vendors availability. Then, for each fruit, take rows of data that are barely needed to meet or exceed the total order size. At that point, compute how much will be purchased from each vendor (it is their available amount if total is not exceeded, or only enough to meet remaining of the total). Once you know how much is purchased from each vendor, you then do the weighted average to get the final price per unit. Not sure if this is what you are looking for. At least, this code should give you ideas on using `dplyr` package in many ways. :)

```
library(dplyr)
fruit_orders %>%
  arrange(fruit, price_per_unit, vendor_availability) %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  slice(1:which.max(Total_Order <= cumsum(vendor_availability))) %>%
  mutate(purchased_from_vendor = ifelse(cumsum(vendor_availability) <=
                                          max(Total_Order),
                                        vendor_availability,
                                        max(Total_Order) - cumsum(vendor_availability) + vendor_availability)) %>%
  summarise(total_unit_price =
              sum(purchased_from_vendor * price_per_unit) / max(Total_Order))
```

Resulting output is as follows:

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

```
   fruit total_unit_price
  <fctr>            <dbl>
1  apple            0.081
2 orange            0.250
```

Comment: Thank you- this works very well!

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr solution almost identical to that of @Gopala - the only difference is in the slice expression, and slightly different ways of calculAtion/assignment.

```
require(dplyr)
fruit_detail <- fruit_orders %>% 

  ## order by price to allocate purchases lowest to highest - group by fruit
  arrange(fruit, price_per_unit) %>%
  group_by (fruit) %>%

  mutate(
    cum_vendor_availability = cumsum(vendor_availability) - vendor_availability,
    can_buy = (Total_Order - cum_vendor_availability),
    units = ifelse(can_buy <=0, 0, ifelse(can_buy >= vendor_availability, vendor_availability, can_buy)),
    cost = units * price_per_unit)

fruit_summary <-  fruit_detail %>% 
  group_by(fruit) %>% 
  summarize(ave_price = sum(cost) / sum(units))

fruit_summary

  fruit ave_price
  (fctr)     (dbl)
1  apple     0.081
2 orange     0.250
```

Comment: thank you- this worked perfectly for my needs!